# Laravel - Javascript can not find images when path changes

Tags: javascript, laravel, assets

in my Laravel template I include a JS-file.

Here I am using a plugin which needs images.

```
    $.backstretch([
        "../img/header-tt-big.jpg",
        "../img/header-soccer-big.jpg"
    ]
```

So.. when I go to my "startpage" like this it is working:
http://localhost/project/public/de/p1

When I go here it won't work
http://localhost/project/public/de/p1/register

I would have to add another "../" for all images in the JS-file. How can I make this work without changing the array manually everytime?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @ITroubs pointed out, if you have the javascript code inside a blade template (`<script>` tag) you can and should use `asset()` to generate the URLs. But don't forget the extra quotes so javascript interprets it as string.

```
$.backstretch([
    "{{ asset('img/header-tt-big.jpg') }}",
    "{{ asset('img/header-soccer-big.jpg') }}"
]
```

However if you have the javascript code in separate .js files (which is actually recommended) you can't do that. Instead I suggest you define a `assetBaseUrl` in your layout blade template *before* the javascript code that needs it:

```
<script>
    var assetBaseUrl = "{{ asset('') }}";
</script>
```

Usage:

```
$.backstretch([
    assetBaseUrl + "img/header-tt-big.jpg",
    assetBaseUrl + "img/header-soccer-big.jpg"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use blade then write the backstretch like this:

```
$.backstretch([
    "{{asset("img/header-tt-big.jpg")}}",
    "{{asset("img/header-soccer-big.jpg")}}"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I added the script as inline in a script-tag. But i did put it in a seperate file like p1-inline.blade.php. So i can just include that one. Thank you ;)